# How to setup Google Cloud Storage as a media backend for Django?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-django-storages

I am using Django Storages [google] https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html

I deployed my app to App engine using no-promote so that I test it out but everytime i upload an image, I get this error   *Cannot determine path without bucket name.'*.

Please note am using Django admin to make the upload and my service account key is at the root of my project.

My bucket name is 'kyimages' and in models.py, `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='kyimages/', blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: The upload_to field just appends 'kyimages/' to the blob name it will write (paths/folders in gcs are virtual). You still need to configure the storage either by overriding the default storage class, or specify the storage with the ImageField(.... storage= ) option

Comment: Thanks Inigo. Instead of GS_BUCKET, I was using GS_MEDIA_BUCKET.